# Chevy Equinox Cabin (Interior) Temperature Sensor

Tags: sensor, temperature, equinox, cabin

Does anyone know the location of the Cabin (Interior, **NOT ambient**) Temperature sensor?  This is for a 2012 Chevy Equinox 2.4L LT2.
TIA

Scott

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's usually located right near the A/C controls in the beauty ring which surrounds things. Look for a small slotted area about 1/2" square or so. This is a general placement, but one I've seen often in GM vehicles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and I understand what you're saying to look for, but I just spent about a half hour looking all over your suggested places, and no joy.  As a volunteer Paramedic and Ham, I have had most of that area apart over the years installing radios and emergency lights, and this is driving me crazy as I cannot find anything on the net, or on the car that, looks like the temp sensor.  Thanks again,

Comment: Stupid question on my part here, but it does have auto temperature controls?

Comment: [This is what it looks like](https://www.rockauto.com/info/315/15-51265_Alternate1__ra_p.jpg).

Comment: Yes, it has auto temp, and it has worked perfectly for 6 years, just started having a problem this summer.  And thank you, I know exactly what it looks like and where to get the replacement, I just don't know where to find it in the vehicle to remove and replace it.